# Android screen layout design

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to the android.I need the xml layout for the following widget can any one please help me [image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/card-design

http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.in/2013/12/android-card-layout.html

Try this for better layout. Hope its help you.

Comment: Link-only answers are deprecated, on StackOverflow